# DrawerLayout performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a time recording app which consists of two activities. One for managing the projects and one for time record manipulation.

The core of both activities are views I draw on my own. TimeRecord activity has a self-made calendar and Project-Activity has a TreeView.

Yesterday I started to play with the DrawerLayout. Everything works fine but I'm a bit unconfident because I had to merge all my code that was split in two activities into one.

I guess it's the easiest way to post some screenshots so that you can get a clear understanding of my app and I don't have to write many more paragraphs that describe how my app looks like :P

First the timerecord activity.
Second the open drawer with the former projects activity.[image: Timerecord activity]

[image: OpenDrawer (former Project activity)]

I already tested it on my devices (even older ones) and performance seems still to be ok. I just feel a little unconfident because now my activity has grown up enormously (same thing for layout-xml file).

Can anyone share his experience with me.
Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your `Activity` into two `Fragments`, one fragment with Tree and second fragment with calendar. This would be better option and you will be able to reuse fragments later.

Comment: Thanks for very fast response :)
I agree 100% that this would increase code quality but I guess the performace wouldn't benefit from that?!

Comment: Probably not. But you get cleaner code and easier to manage and reuse. Its up to your custom views to make them efficient

Comment: Maybe if I load the fragment only when it is needed? But this may cause a delay when the user want's to show the tree...

Comment: Don't do that. Like I said make your tree optimized, with as few views as possible, and don't redraw it every second. ;]

Comment: I guess the redraw shouldn't be the problem since only one view can be active at a time. So this shouldn’t differ much than in my previous (two activity) implementation. I think my question is nearly impossible to answer for anyone. I have to test it much more. Maybe also check memory and CPU consumption.